# Nesting Issue In Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, database, core-data, categories

I have created a database in which I have to store contacts in various categories. The issue comes when I have to create Sub categories in a Category like :-

**Categories ->
           Sub Categories->
                          Contacts**

But the Categories can also have Contacts like

**Categories -> Contacts**

where the sub categories can also have contacts. I figured that nesting in core data would be used. How can I achieve this kind of a relationship ? How do I save the sub categories into the categories even though they are of the same entity ?

I have attached my core data entity relationship model here :-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem creating a "self" referencing relationship in CoreDate.
In other words, An entity may have a relationship of its own kind.

The only difference in your case between a `Category` and a `SubCategory` is the existence of a `parent` entity.
So there is no need to define a new entity for that part.

You can simply define a relationship:

`Category`.`parent` of type `Category` (say to-one in this case)

and a reverse relationship of:

`Category`.`subCategories` of type `NSSet` (to-many in this case) containing `Category` objects.

You can set all that up in your interface builder.

Now, since `Category` has a relationship with `Contact` so does all the "sub-categories" will have that relationship.

If you like your "sub-categories" to have additional properties, simply create a new entity an make it inherit from your `Category` entity (keeping the above setting I described).
and add to it the new properties.

Comment: So you mean that I create a relationship to the same entity Category from Category itself ?